# How to force HP-UFT to ignore untrusted security certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, firefox, vbscript, hp-uft

I'm new to HP-UFT and need to automate a number of test environments using HTTPS. These environments do not have valid security certificates (they're self-signed) & I'd like to configure UFT to ignore them for Firefox/Chrome. With Selenium/Java, this is as simple as setting the driver capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
driver.get("untrusted_site_url");
```

The browser will then not display the security warnings & go straight to the target site.

Is there any way to do something similar in UFT?

Let me tell you what I can't do: Add certificates to the test environments or upgrade my version of UFT (out of my control unfortunately).

And this is what I've tried:

- Importing the untrusted certificate into the browser (Firefox doesn't allow it & Chrome ignores it).
- Adding extensions/add-ons that supposedly force the browser to ignore certificates (none of them work).
- Automating the warning screens (Firefox: UFT can click the "Add Exception..." button without error, but the "Add Security Exception" dialog is not displayed. Chrome: I don't know what the heck is going on there - can't inspect any of the warning screen elements with the developer tools).
- Changing certain about:config settings in Firefox (eg: security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling, browser.ssl_override_behavior). None of them have stopped the warning message being displayed.

Bear in mind that I'm inside a secured, corporate network & thus, certain internet settings are unavailable to me. And yes, I understand the risks of switching off these warnings, but need to automate these internal sites.

I'm using UFT v12.53 build 2027, 
Firefox 54.0.1 & 
Chrome v53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit).

Comment: "I need to automate these internal sites" is not compatible with "a secured, corporate network". Get a network for testing. Or ask your admins for help. If you need this, they must enable it. If they won't, you know you should not do it. Fight your way through that formal rergulations jungle. But don't try to bypass it. You will have trouble keeping any solution alive with every browser update.

The rules are there for a reason, and if you need an exception, you'll get it.